# What is my Cronjobs problem?

Tags: php, cron

I have no idea whats going on. But I have a script that looks like this. Cron job refuses to run it:

```
include_once 'class_lib/mime_mail/mimeDecode.php';
include_once 'class_lib/Mail/IMAPv2.php';
include_once 'inc-functions.php';
include_once "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/class_lib/DbFuctioneer.php";

$dbFuctioneer = new DbFuctioneer();
```

Everything works well when I remove:

```
$dbFuctioneer = new DbFuctioneer();
```

Even when DbFuctioneer() looks like this:

```
<?php

class DbFuctioneer { 
    function dbCountMatches( $count) {
        return $count;
    }
}
```

Does Cron have a problem with Classes in his Jobs?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

---

It seems

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

is empty when cron is running its job.

Why is that?

Comment: does commandline PHP have access to the $_SERVER superglobal and is it set to the value you expect?

Comment: Could it be that your startup script (.bashrc or whatever) does not set those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` present when you call the script from the command line.

That variable (along with many others like `REQUEST_URI`, `SCRIPT_NAME`, `HTTP_HOST`....) is set by Apache, which is not running in your case.

You need to set the root directory manually.

To find out whether you are running in the context of a web site or from the command line, use [php_sapi_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php).

You could set `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` manually when running on the command line, but I would rather use a completely new constant or variable to put the path into.

Comment: @Álvaro you're right, I edited to make the wording clearer. @Marius you're welcome.

Comment: Another option is to use curl to run the script via the command line.  The benefit to that is the script is being run in the same manner it was designed, but unless it's a localhost script, lack of an internet connection may restrict it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following (run  your script from the command line) and check the output is correct:

```
print("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/class_lib/DbFuctioneer.php");
```

Most likely its broken.